# Get specific text from webpage

Tags: php

I have this Page [Test1](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php) on this other page [test](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test.php)

I have this PHP code running to get some code from test1.

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@type='button']/@onclick");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The result is this

```
OnPlay('sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/120704 cod ', ' eu - Nr.1 in tv ! ')
OnPlay('sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/140601 cod ', ' eu - Nr.1 in tv ! ')     
OnPlay('sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/124589 cod ', ' eu - Nr.1 tv') 
OnPlay('sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/589994 cod ', ' eu - tv ') 
OnPlay('sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/ cod ', ' eu - tv ')
```

But I need only this data from all of that: `sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/140601

All of them.

How to get rid of extra text or how to get gest the(sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/140601,sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/120704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is always formatted like this, you can simply use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the `sop://` URL.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');


libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@type='button']/@onclick");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
            $content = $node->nodeValue;
            $content = explode("'", $content, 3);
            $content = explode(" ", $content[1], 2);
            $sop = $content[0];
            unset($content);
            var_dump($sop);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this seems god but  haas this result:
string(36) "sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/120704"
ai need only sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/120704 withouth any others characters.

Comment: Or mabe is posible that the string (36) grt rid of2

Comment: Because I used [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead of echo it shows the data type. If you use echo it will only display the `sop://...`.

Comment: New i have this sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/120704OnPlay('sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/140601 cod ', ' eu - Nr.1 in tv ! ')
is ther a wai to separete them in new linws or mibe not to sho up at all

Comment: Is [this](http://pastebin.com/rSN476YA) giving you that result? By the way, you can remove the first `echo` if you don't need that data for debugging.

Comment: Ther is a wai to put them on separate lines not just one??

Comment: That's why I added `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');`, so it gets displayed with all the line breaks and tabs and such. But you can also _View Source_ or put the output between `<pre>` tags.

Comment: How to put <pre> to the outpu?? becau with thwe header thei are stil on one line!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. What exactly do you want to use the outputted data for? Anyway, this code will give you everything on a new line: http://pastebin.com/PiSBCxwS (if you prefer HTML: http://pastebin.com/2mLQjF86)

Comment: One more Thing. lets say i need just de second Sop:// can it be done and how?

Comment: Well, for example, you could create an array (`$sopArr=array()`) and instead of `echo`ing `$sop` you could add it to the array (`$sopArr[] = $sop;`). At the end of the script, you could then read the 2nd `sop` as follows: `$theSecondSop = $sopArr[1];`. (And then `echo` it like this: `echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($theSecondSop,ENT_QUOTES)."'>Click here for the SOP</a>";`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need do some string manipulation on resultant OnClick event handlers text.

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@type='button']/@onclick");
$value_text = array();
$index = 0;
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            value_text[$index++] = getReuiredValue($node->nodeValue);
        }
    }
    //value_text will contain all required values as array
    print_r($value_text);
}


    function getReuiredValue($on_play)
    {
   $pos = strpos($on_play, 'cod ');
   //following call will parse the OnPlay string and get the required value out of string
   $updated_on_play = substr($on_play, 8, (strlen($on_play) - (strlen($on_play) - $pos) - 8));
   $updated_on_play = trim($updated_on_play);
   return  $updated_on_play;
   }
?>
```